# List of all Read Only Fields on an Object

Tags: apex, custom-field

Is there a way to get the list of all the Read Only fields on an Object ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are you trying to get this information for the running user?

Answer (score 4):

field is read-only if it is Accessible, but not Updateble and not Creatable. To get this information you can use [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) class.

For example, to get all read-only fields on `Account` for running user:

```
Set<SObjectField> readOnlyFields = new Set<SObjectField>();
for(SObjectField field :sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()){
    if(field.getDescribe().isAccessible()
        && !field.getDescribe().isUpdateable()
        && !field.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
        readOnlyFields.add(field);
    }
}
```

All read-only fields would be stored in `readOnlyFields` collection.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. isAccessible(), isUpdateable() and isCreateable() display field-level permissions for the running user. If the user does not has access to the fields, the formula evaluates to false, even though it is NOT a system field and not read-only.